# Polymer core-submenu not showing the submenu but only its items

Tags: javascript, html, polymer, submenu

I am trying to work with Polymer 0.5.5 and its core features. When I tried to use Menu mixed with some SubMenu, the output is not was I expected. See sample source code:

```
<core-menu selected="{{Selected}}" selectedItem={{MenuItem}}>
  <core-submenu icon="print" label="Printer" selectedItem={{SubMenuItem}}>
    <core-item label="Printer Papers"></core-item>
    <core-item label="Printer Networks"></core-item>
  </core-submenu>
  <core-item icon="cloud" label="HotFolder"></core-item>
  <core-item icon="settings" label="Settings"></core-item>
</core-menu>
```

In my case, only the items of the subMenu are showing up, i.e. the Submenu entry and its icon are missing, and I can't get the label via the SubMenuItem. The selected variable is 0 in this case which is logical but doesn't help...
My browser is Chrome 40.x which should be sufficient in terms of compatibility.

Comment: Can you make a codepen/plunker?

Comment: Here is the link to the github of my current work, plunker does not support Polymer sadly, or I missed it... https://github.com/MeTaNoV/poly-conf-editor

Comment: I modified my main HTML to reference the Polymer directly on their website, the result is: http://plnkr.co/edit/gXVR7TmNiu80kq07s3AZ . Note that there is also a rendering bug when I tried to change the size of icon-button and paper-button via css...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You miss an import of the core-submenu element. Try an import of core-elements instead, it worked in one of my tests. In your document this should be something like that:

```
<link rel="import" href="//www.polymer-project.org/components/core-elements/core-elements.html">
```

Comment: Oh damn... Since there were no folder for submenu, I though falsely its definition was contained in the menu one... Thanks, it work perfectly now!

Comment: By the way, is there a quick way to check if a custom element import is missing when you try to use it in your code?

Comment: If such a feature exists, I am not aware or that. The only way is to check if the shadow DOM of each element is available by inspection. Chrome is efficient for this.

Comment: I found this in the Debugging Tips and Tricks from the Polymer site, could be indeed handy! https://gist.github.com/ebidel/cea24a0c4fdcda8f8af2